# Jquery / JS Array multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay first off I do not know JS or Jquery, but when I need to make a change or addition on my website - I always fiddle around and find a way to make it work off of existing code.  But I can't figure this out.

I have a grid of Colored buttons as options on a product.  Standard colors do not cost anything additional, Chrome colors have a separate "array" of pricing that adds to the total product cost. This is already in effect and works well.  This code is below:

```
$("#accentcolor").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({
stop: function () {
chromeColors = 0;
originalBaseTotal = baseTotal;
accentcolors = new Array();
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
if (this.title != "") accentcolors.push(this.title);
if (this.title != "" && this.title.indexOf("chrome") > -1) chromeColors++;
if (this.title != "" && this.title.indexOf("metallic") > -1) chromeColors++;
});
resetProductPrices();
updateProductPrices();
updateTotal();
}
});
```

Now I am trying to add a 3rd set of colors to this setup, that are called Fades.  I have created a new pricing array for this, and it is called "fadeColors" whereas the chromes are called "chromeColors" above.  I need help adding the Fades into this code above.
What I have done is below, but only the new Fade colors will adjust the price. When clicking any of the existing Chrome colors now they do not adjust the price.

```
$("#accentcolor").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({
stop: function () {
chromeColors = 0;
fadeColors = 0;
originalBaseTotal = baseTotal;
accentcolors = new Array();
$(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
if (this.title != "") accentcolors.push(this.title);
if (this.title != "" && this.title.indexOf("chrome") > -1) chromeColors++;
if (this.title != "" && this.title.indexOf("metallic") > -1) chromeColors++;
if (this.title != "" && this.title.indexOf("fade") > -1) fadeColors++;
});
resetProductPrices();
updateProductPrices();
updateTotal();
}
});
```

Comment: can you create fiddle or snippet here. @user2016709

Comment: I don't know what that means hahah - I'm sure I can if you can explain?  I can provide a link to the live website with full code if that helps? or is that not allowed?

Comment: add your html and javascript code here https://jsfiddle.net/ if css add that also. this sample running example creation. @user2016709

Comment: is this right? I tried to take out all of the paypal and personal identification so hopefully that didnt mess anything up.  https://jsfiddle.net/ra1mzdq3/